# Template parameter default to a later one

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-templates, default-arguments

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480771/is-it-possible-to-infer-or-default-an-earlier-template-parameter-from-a-later-on) doesn't answer my question so I'll ask it here:

Basically I want to write a template function

```
template <typename Out, typename In>
Out f(In x);
```

Here I always need to specify `Out` when calling `f`.  I don't want to do it every time, so I basically want

```
template <typename Out = In, typename In>
Out f(In x);
```

Which means if I don't specify `Out`, it will default to `In`.  However, this is not possible in C++11.

So my question is, is there any way to achieve the effect:

1. calling `f(t)` will instantiate `f<T,T>(t)` or more generally `f<typename SomeThing<T>::type, T>`
2. calling `f<U>(t)` will instantiate `f<U, T>(t)`

Comment: What is the difference between `<typename Out = In, typename In>` and `<typename Out, typename In = Out>`?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain the first order does not know how to set the default of `Out` to `In` because it hasn't seen `In` yet at that point.

Comment: @icando why is reversing the order of template arguments not an option for you? see my answer. (other answers that proposed this are gone so I missed the arguments why they were not satisfactory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a PERFECT solution here!  `f<const int&>` won't work because a function can't return a reference to a temporary, not related to the techniques used here.

```
[hidden]$ cat a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template <typename Out, typename In>
Out f_impl(In x) {
  cout << "Out=" << typeid(Out).name() << " " << "In=" << typeid(In).name() << endl;
  return Out();
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct FirstOf {
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct SecondOf {
  typedef U type;
};

template <typename... Args, typename In>
typename enable_if<sizeof...(Args) <= 1, typename FirstOf<Args..., In>::type>::type f(In x) {
  typedef typename FirstOf<Args..., In>::type Out;
  return f_impl<Out, In>(x);
}

template <typename... Args, typename In>
typename enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 2, typename FirstOf<Args...>::type>::type f(In x) {
  typedef typename FirstOf<Args...>::type Out;
  typedef typename SecondOf<Args...>::type RealIn;
  return f_impl<Out, RealIn>(x);
}

int main() {
  f(1);
  f(1.0);
  f<double>(1);
  f<int>(1.0);
  f<int>(1);
  f<const int>(1);
  f<int, double>(1);
  f<int, int>(1);
  f<double, double>(1);
}
[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp
[hidden]$ ./a.out
Out=i In=i
Out=d In=d
Out=d In=i
Out=i In=d
Out=i In=i
Out=i In=i
Out=i In=d
Out=i In=i
Out=d In=d
```

Comment: I'm a bit surprised `template <typename... Args, typename In>` is legal.  :)  And shouldn't you use perfect forwarding on `f(In x)` when forwarding to `f_impl`?

Comment: I am surprised too.  I am very surprised that by using varadic template one can actually tell whether you are calling with f(x) or f<T>(x) or f<T,U>(x), etc.

Answer (score 8):

You probably never want to specify `In` but rather have it deduced, right?

In this case you need to overload the function:

```
template <typename Out, In>
Out f(In x);

template <typename T>
T f(T x);
```

Call it:

```
f(42);
f<float>(42);
```

… but unfortunately that’s ambiguous for `f<int>(42)`. No matter, we can use SFINAE to disable one of the overloads appropriately:

```
template <
    typename Out,
    typename In,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<Out, In>::value>::type
>
Out f(In x);

template <typename T>
T f(T x);
```

In order to avoid redundancy in the implementation, let both functions dispatch to a common implementation, `f_impl`.

[Here’s a working example:](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=02fad63ba62d4d2f73973e2455dba514)

```
template <typename Out, typename In>
Out f_impl(In x) {
    std::cout << "f<" << typeid(Out).name() <<
                 ", " << typeid(In).name() <<
                 ">(" << x << ")\n";
    return x;
}

template <
    typename Out,
    typename In,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<Out, In>::value>::type
>
Out f(In x) {
    std::cout << "f<Out, In>(x):\t ";
    return f_impl<Out, In>(x);
}

template <typename T>
T f(T x) {
    std::cout << "f<T>(x):\t ";
    return f_impl<T, T>(x);
}


int main() {
    f(42);
    f<float>(42);
    f<int>(42);
}
```

Comment: What happens if I call `f<int>(4.2)`?

Comment: @K-ballo The correct thing. [Try it.](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7b5fc26fb42eb06e33f844e2c0a805dc)

Comment: This generally looks good with a little drawback: f<int>(5) will cause compiler error: ambiguous overload.  Anyway to solve the issue?

Comment: @icando Good point, it can be solved with a `disable_if`. I’ll adapt my examples.

Comment: Also both overloads are actually valid in case of f<float>(42).  Could you point out which part of the standard guarantees f<float,int> is prefered over f<float>?

Comment: @icando I can’t point to the section but one of the overloads requires an implicit conversion of `42` to `float` while the other is an exact match so there’s no ambiguity.

Comment: @icando: In that case both might be valid, but `f<float, int>` is a better match, since it perfectly matches the type the argument, while `f<float>` needs an implicit conversion. Should be in the overload resolution section

Comment: @KonradRudolph, still imperfect with your answer: `f<const int>(5)` or `f<const int&>(5)` will both be ambiguous.  Maybe I shouldn't be so picky, but I think it is quite challenging to make it perfect, and it will be fun if we can do it :-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I think the essential imperfection with your answer is, ideally `f<const int>(5)` should go to the case `f<const int, int>`, even `f<int>(5)` should go to the case `f<int, int>`, but the `f<const int>` or `f<int>` are the perfect overload resolutions so you have to disable `f<U,T>` instead.  Maybe there is just no perfect solution under current C++.

Comment: I have a perfect solution below now.  Take a look at it.

Comment: You can replace the second prototype of f with `template <bool=true,typename T> T f(T x)` so it is ignored when you specify a template parameter (then you can remove the enable_if).

Comment: @Marc That’s f***ing smart.

Answer (score 4):

You may not need it here, but here is a classical technique:

```
struct Default
{
  template <typename Argument, typename Value>
    struct Get {
      typedef Argument type;
    };

  template <typename Value>
    struct Get <Default, Value> {
      typedef Value type;
    };
};

template <typename Out = Default, typename In>
typename Default::Get<Out, In>::type f(In x);
```

Comment: This still requires the existance of a type that you can't put as `Out`.  For example, calling `f<Default>(5)` will still goes to `f<int, int>` instead of `f<Default, int>`.  This is not what I want.  If there exists such type that I can't put into the parameter list, then I can do a lot of things, e.g. disable_if.  But such requirement makes it imperfect.

Comment: If I make Default non-movable, you won't be able to declare a function that returns it anyway, so there is no loss here.

Comment: You could even use a preexisting non-movable type like std::mutex as the dummy type. `f<std::mutex,whatever>` is already meaningless, nothing to lose.